# How to return promise after iterating over an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, promise

I am using `bluebird` & `lodash` and am trying to figure out how I can return a promise after iterating over an object? For example, I want to add a key/value pair to each object THEN after adding a key/value pair to each object, I want to print the result:

```
  var cars = {  
        audi:[  
           {  
              model:'r8',
              year:'2012'
           },
           {  
              model:'rs5',
              year:'2013'
           }
        ],
        ford:[  
           {  
              model:'mustang',
              year:'2012'
           },
           {  
              model:'fusion',
              year:'2015'
           }
        ],
        kia:[  
           {  
              model:'optima',
              year:'2012'
           }
        ]
  }

  _.forOwn(cars, function(value, key) {
     key.processed = true;
  }).then(function(cars) {
     //print modified cars object here
     console.log(cars);
  });
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `_.forOwn` is synchronous - get rid of `.then(function(cars) {` and the final `});` - et voilà - no promise needed

Comment: The previous commenter is saying there's no benefit to trying to return a promise from a simple iteration, which is not asynchronous--it simply runs as fast as the javascript engine can perform it. If what you're saying, however, is that the iteration needs to kick off a bunch of processes which are each asynchronous, then that's a very different question from the one you've *actually* asked. In that case, you'd do something like `map` that returns an array of promises (one from every element), then after each promise returns, checks to see if it's the final one and kicks off a 'done' promise.

Comment: So to confirm - the `_.forOwn` will always finish first before the `console.log(cars)`? @ErikE does `map` work on objects? I thought `map` only works on arrays...

Comment: Yes, it will finish first. But if you kick off an asynchronous event in the loop, the `cars` object may not be updated yet when the `console.log` runs. As for `map`, I said "something like `map`". I don't know lodash at all, really, but all I mean is that you want to iterate over the object, then return a value from each (a promise) instead of just exiting the function. You could do `var promises = [];`, then inside the `forOwn` do `promises.push(fnThatReturnsAPromise());`. Finally, you can work with those promises after `forOwn` is done (which will happen very fast).

Comment: let me clarify - my intention is to use the final `cars` object in another function... thats why I need to know that all the key/value pairs have been added to each `car` before I continue onto the next function

Comment: There's got to be some kind of output-returning version of `map` in lodash, right? Or you can write your own. You know, you **still** haven't spelled out what you plan to do to each item in the `cars` object. **Will you perform asynchronous operations there or not?**

Comment: i will perform asynchronous operations on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, you could do something like this (note: no lodash, because I don't use lodash, but the concept shown should be adaptable to lodash)

```
function someAsyncFunction(car) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            car.processed = true;
            resolve(car);
        }, 1000 * Math.random() + 1000);
    });
}

Promise.all(Object.keys(cars).map(function(key) {
    return someAsyncFunction(cars[key]);
})).then(function(results) { // results will be an array of the values resolved in the promises
    console.log(cars);
});
```